# Grails: getting info using hibernate results in old data

Tags: hibernate, grails

I am managing list of folders in the DB (Folder table). I am creating folders and fetching folders, each folder stores id of the previous folder in the list (sort of a linked list) so a folder can be inserted "between" two existing folders. So a folder has an 'id' field and a 'prev_folder_id' field. 'prev_folder_id' might be nil of an id of other existing folder.

When adding new folder:

1. Creating and storing new folder in DB
2. Changing the prev_folder_id of the next folder in the linked list to point to the new folder.

The data in the DB is changed correctly. However, the problem i see is that when fetching list of folder, the next folder still points to the old prev_folder_id and not to the new one. If i will fire the same fetch request several times, i will sometimes get the old info and sometimes the new and correct info.

The following is my hibernate configufation in DataSource.groovy:

```
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = false
    cache.use_query_cache = false
//    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
    singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
    flush.mode = 'auto' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional context

    format_sql = false
    use_sql_comments = true
}
```

My guess that the problem is with caching, however all caching options are disabled. What might cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it has to do with this:

```
flush.mode = 'auto'
```

See http://vladmihalcea.com/the-dark-side-of-hibernate-auto-flush/

You can set it to 'always' if you're ok with trading a bit of optimization for consistency.

Comment: I changed the flush mode to always, but the problem still happens.